# OpenCv overlay multiple Mat partly using masks

Tags: c++, opencv, mask

Hi following up on this brillant way of copying polygons to an other `Mat` in [OpenCv overlay two Mat (drawings not images) with transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45131216/opencv-overlay-two-mat-drawings-not-images-with-transparency/45132718#45132718) I need to advanced this a bit.

Besides just copying Mats with polygons, I need to copy these polygons ONTO a image. Below you can find my MWE of this.

Following the above mentioned answer I load an additional image called `bg` in this case (as well `100x100px`).  What I believed is using `inRange` again on the `result` gives me the `mask` of all polygons (which is working). And than using `copyTo` to copy all that is in the mask. It copies the pixels from the "background image", but colouring the polygons in black insted of its regular colours.

Any ideas what I forgot to consider in this case?

PS: drawing the polygons directly onto the image is not possible. The code below is just a MWE and in the code below I left out an loop for readability reasons.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cv::Mat bg = imread("bg.png");
    cv::Mat m1(100, 100, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0));


    cv::Mat m2(m1);
    cv::Mat m3(m1);
    cv::Mat m4(m1);

    cv::polylines(m1, std::vector<cv::Point>{cv::Point{ 100, 20 }, cv::Point{ 0, 40 }}, true, cv::Scalar(6, 6, 255, 255));
    cv::polylines(m2, std::vector<cv::Point>{cv::Point{ 100, 100 }, cv::Point{ 0, 0 }}, true, cv::Scalar(192, 112, 0, 255));
    cv::polylines(m3, std::vector<cv::Point>{cv::Point{ 0, 50 }, cv::Point{ 100, 50 }}, true, cv::Scalar(0, 228, 0, 255));
    cv::polylines(m4, std::vector<cv::Point>{cv::Point{ 20, 0 }, cv::Point{ 20, 100 }}, true, cv::Scalar(0, 228, 255, 0 ));


    cv::Mat mask;
    cv::Mat result(m1.clone());


    cv::inRange(m2, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), mask);
    mask = 255 - mask; // invert the mask
    m2.copyTo(result, mask);

    cv::inRange(result, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), mask);
    m3.copyTo(result, mask);

    cv::inRange(result, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), mask);
    m4.copyTo(result, mask);

    cv::inRange(result, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), mask);
    bg.copyTo(result, mask);


    namedWindow("result", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("result", result);
}
```